# How can I get months in date order in excel box plot

Tags: excel, boxplot

I created a box plot in Excel that shows how many days it takes to do something by month.  The months don't show in date order.  Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Is the source data in date order?

Comment: For some reason I didn't think you could sort in date order.  I went back and did that and it did the trick.  Thanks Jack!